# Understanding HTML 5 and CSS Styling

Tags: css, html

I am used to abusing divs in my web pages. However, I am trying to become better and use html 5 tags.

Generally my HTML5 code looks like this:

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

then I will style the section where the majority of the page's content is.

```
section {
   width:960px;
   height:960px;
   background-image:url("images/bg-img");
}
```

Suppose I want to add another section to this code with different styling. How would I do this to make it semantically correct and SEO friendly?

What I've been doing is `<section id="Content2"></section>` Is that bad?

What are your thoughts guys?

Comment: Try to avoid styling based on tags. If you have a set of styles that represents a *type* of thing, use a class. You can use multiple classes on one element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what elements are available for HTML5: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp

Here are some examples of how to target specific elements. CSS is incredibly powerful and I suggest you check out [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) for a quick teach.

When trying to decide when to use a Class vs an ID, consider if that element will be a one-of-a-kind element, or if there will be multiple of them. If there will be more elements like it, make it a class. If it will be the only one of its type then it is okay to give it an ID. There are arguments towards using only classes (has to do with specificity) rather than giving some elements ID's, but there is no 'Correct' method.

```css
section.tree {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

section.wall {
  width: 50%;
  background: orange;
}

section.tree .acorn {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}

section.library>p {
  background: pink;
}

.first {
  font-size: 23pt;
}
```

```html
<section class="tree">
  This is the tree section
</section>

<section class="wall">
  This is the wall section
</section>

<section class="tree">
  <section class="acorn">
    This is the acorn section
  </section>
</section>

<section class="library">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <p>The last paragraph</p>
</section>

<section class="tree library">
  <p class='first'>A paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <p>The last paragraph</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Will I be penalized in SEO for attaching a class or id to a section element?

Comment: @Brixsta No. Fairly confident about that.